# Soundcloud Widget & Events.SEEK

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am using the Soundcloud player widget and want to tap into the SEEK Event.  The problem I have is that the event parameter for e.currentPosition is display the previous current position - not the current position that I have seeked to.

```
 widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function (e) {

                      var test;
                });
```

If you put a break point on the test for a song you can see what I mean.  Is it possible to get the location that has been seeked to rather than where it started?

Answer (score 0):

Bit hacky but I found it does the job - just pause the widget and wait for it to update to the new position - once it has do what you want with the new position, continue playing the track and clear the checking interval.

```
var oldpos = e.currentPosition;
widget.pause();

var waiter = setInterval(function(){
    widget.getPosition(function(pos){
        if (pos != oldpos){
            // pos is the position that was skipped to.  
            widget.play();
            clearInterval(waiter);
        }
    });
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using the SEEK event listener?

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.SEEK, function(e) {
  alert('New seek position: '+e.currentPosition);
});
```

This works for me.